# Jquery Delegate event working on one of the two selectors only

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("body").on("change", "input[type='checkbox'],input[type=radio]", function(event){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change',function() {
    var that = this;

    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("remember-label")){
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", function() {
          return that.checked ? "#C0E9F7" : "";
      });
    }

  });

  $("input[type=radio]").on('click',function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).siblings().css("backgroundColor","");
    $(this).parents().eq(1).css("backgroundColor","#C0E9F7");

  });

});
```

while i guess this should work, it works only for radio buttons. Since each time the content changes dynamically i have to put both selectors as sometimes radio buttons are added to the DOM and some other times checkboxes.

the problem is that the click area of inputs becomes unclickable unless you explicitly click on the checkbox or radio button instead of the label that covers the whole area.

here is html (it has rails in it but you can understand the structure)

```
<label for="choice_<%= choice.id %>">
            <%= radio_button_tag("choice","#{choice.id}",false,class:"radio big-radio") %>
            <% if choice.image? %>
              <%= image_tag rewrite_url(choice.image_url(:resized)), class:"choice-image" %>
            <% else %>
              <%= choice.description %>
            <% end %>

          </label>
```

the code is for radio buttons but the same applies for checkboxes.

Comment: Don't bind another event in bound events.

Comment: Why are you creating event handlers inside of an event handler?  Won't that just keep adding more event handlers indefinitely?  Why not just create the event handlers once when the page loads?

Comment: because it does not work. i render the inputs dynamically each time and seems the event handlers are bound to the previous elements that are replaced with the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

why you need to use event handler inside event handler .. simply you can use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("body").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']",function() {
        var that = this;
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("remember-label")){
          $(this).parent().css("background-color", function() {
              return that.checked ? "#C0E9F7" : "";
          });
        }
    });
    $("body").on("click", "input[type=radio]" ,function() {
      $(this).parents().eq(1).siblings().css("backgroundColor","");
      $(this).parents().eq(1).css("backgroundColor","#C0E9F7");
    });
});
```

> **Note:** be sure you include jquery

Comment: yep this is cleaner but still i tried this now. it only binds to one of the inputs each time. I mean imagine i have 3 inputs checkboxes when i click next, checkboxes or radio buttons might appear. for some reason(still with your code) the code works for one of the two input types until i refresh the page and start over again where it could potentially work with only radio buttons. does that make sense?the other type of radio button becomes completely unselectable unless i click explicitly on the checkbox/radio where the label which cover a lot of the area should trigger that. added html above

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Please update this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/o70t66ja/  with your code to let us know what's going on

Comment: i cant as there is rails code that dynamically renders a partial file which contains checkboxes or radio buttons each time and i want to bind the events on the newly created dynamic checkboxes/radio buttons

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou after it rendered you can right click and click on inspect elements to open your browser console and copy/paste html code from there

Comment: just did that now - updated your fiddle. But on clicking the next-question button is where it renders a partial again with either checkboxes or radio buttons. What does not work is the label becomes unclickable to be exact. If i click the checkbox itself the css written in jquery is applied correctly.

Comment: Hmm what i just found is that the first time i see the inputs, if they are checkboxes and i click next, and the new elements are checkboxes the label does not trigger the checkbox, but if i click next again and it shows radio buttons, it works just fine. and vice-versa.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou I really appreciate what you trying to do and your efforts to expain the issue .. take on consider that we don't see your website like you see it .. so seriously about me or anyone else here can't help you while we can't see the live demo of your code .. Just to let us see what is going wrong there .. sorry about that but this is the truth

Answer (score 0):

You should bind one time only:

```
$("body").on("change", "input[type='checkbox'],input[type=radio]", function(event){
     // here you can check if this is check box or radio

        if($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
            // do this
        }else{
           // do for radios
        }

 });
```

Comment: tried this now, sadly it works only for radio buttons something is wrong with checkboxes. It works only for the first time you check checkboxes. after that when i dynamically replace the checkboxes the label covering the checkbox becomes unclickable where as for the radio button all is fine.